# Pre-dual of a lattice is a lattice?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, vector-lattices, banach-lattices

> Let $X$ be a Banach space such that its dual $X'$ is a Banach lattice. Then must $X$ also be a lattice?

I know that if $X$ is a lattice, then so is its dual $X'$. However, I was wondering is the converse direction necessarily true or are there well-known counterexamples? Of course, a reference would suffice.

Comment: [This](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiZr4-L3Oj1AhVLJUQIHd18DbY4ChAWegQIJhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Ftran%2F1968-131-02%2FS0002-9947-1968-0222604-8%2FS0002-9947-1968-0222604-8.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1adHI3KoCQ19lKFNVFAhdm) suggests the answer is "not necessarily".

Comment: [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=g2m3DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=predual+l1+not+lattice&source=bl&ots=_layorkls9&sig=ACfU3U3NFD618Zd9Mth02-QuTiST-kmDWw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiuqO-yy-r1AhXvm2oFHXahD_Y4ChDoAXoECBIQAw#v=onepage&q=predual%20l1%20not%20lattice&f=false) it is mentioned that the space constructed in [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02762798) paper gives a counterexample.